# Is $ x^n-y^n$ is a product of coprime factors?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

In the expression: $x^n-y^n$, if $n>2$ and $x,y$ are relatively prime, are the factors $x-y$ and $ x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+.....$ always coprime? Why? Please exclude the cases where $x-y=\pm 1$ and $\pm 2$. I know it is for $x=2$. Please any input will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x\equiv y\pmod k$ and $k\mid n$, then they're not coprime.

**Proof:**

$x\equiv y\pmod k$, so $k\mid x-y$.

Since $x\equiv y\pmod k$, we have $x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\cdots+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1}\equiv nx^{n-1}\equiv 0\pmod k$, since $k\mid n$. $\:\square$

Answer (score 1):

Take a prime factor $p$ of $x-y$. Then $x\equiv y\pmod p$ and
$$x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}y+\cdots+y^{p-1}\equiv px^{p-1}\equiv 0\pmod p$$

Then, for $n=p$ your two factors are not coprime.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I just use a spreadsheet and try out some numbers. So I picked x = 8, y = 5, and we check whether x^n - y^n is ever a multiple of 9.

Guess what: 8^3 - 5^3 = 512 - 125 = 387 = 9 * 43.

It looks like you didn't spend the slightest bit of thought on this.

Other examples: 9^6 - 4^6 = 58,025 = 25 * 2321.